# Getting article text for movies from the wikipedia api?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

My main goal is to be able to pass in a string containing the name of a movie, get suggestions based on the query, and then load the article text for a chosen movie.

The way I see it, this breaks down into two API calls. One where a user enters a movie name and gets suggestions, and then another API call that loads the article text based on the selected one.

I've tried looking at the wikipedia api but it's very complex and I feel overwhelmed.

---

For the first api call, I've ripped this off from the auto-suggest on the homepage:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=prefixsearch&redirects=&ppprop=displaytitle&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=80&pilimit=6&gpssearch=conan%20the%20barbarian
```

It kinda works. I see a warning and unfortunately it's not limited to movies. But I see a pageId of `3444797` for "Conan the Barbarian (1982 film)" which is what I assume I'd need for that second API call.

For the second API call, I found this in some of the documentation, but it doesn't take in a pageId, and it only returns an "extract" of the article.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=10&exlimit=1&titles=Pet_door&explaintext=1&formatversion=2
```

---

So, to summarize, how can I:

- Get a list of movies based on a given search term
- Get the article text of a given item returned from the previous API call?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, I highly recommend using the search engine provided by the Mediawiki system for better search results. Mediawiki uses an extension called **cirrus search**. You can find more details about how efficiently you can use it by reading [this guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch).

Anyway, to get search results for the movies that are related to a specific search term, you can use the following API:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&formatversion=latest&srsearch="conan the barbarian" articletopic:films](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch)

As you can see, I am using the default search engine to get the results, related to **Conan the barbarian**, and the same API will make sure that the result item is related to the **films** topic.

**Next**, you can use the title in the response (`"title":`), to get the content of the page by using this API:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Conan of Venarium&explaintext=1&formatversion=2](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Conan%20of%20Venarium&explaintext=1&formatversion=2)